# Adding horizontalScroll as subview to UItableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with each cell having eight buttons. I need horizontal scroll to be able to scroll those buttons.

While using this code, i can't see any buttons in cell.

> In view did Load

```
horizontalScroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 270, 320, 60)];
//horizontal scroll is a property of UIViewController

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         // Configure the cell...
         if (cell == nil) 
         {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
          }

int x = 13;
int y=13;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    UIButton *button= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(x, 80, 45, 22);
    [button setTag:i];
    [button setTitle:@"08:30" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0/255 green:234.0/255 blue:234.0/255 alpha:1]];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:13.0];
    [horizontalScroll addSubview:button];
    x +=62;

  }

  [cell addSubview:horizontalScroll];
}
```

However , if i do :

```
   [cell addSubview:button];
```

I can see buttons in cell but cannot scroll them.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: Set content size of scrollview.

Comment: not sure about what your tableview is actually doing but this is very bad code design. If the cell needs a scrollview, it should be the owner of it (not your view controller). you should subclass UITableViewCell and create the scroll view and the buttons inside the cell class

Comment: You can have a look at the two part tutorial of http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1

Comment: My tableview cells are not comprised of buttons only, there are other UI elements in it aswell. I want scroll for just buttons only..

Answer (score 0):

Add `[horizontalScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(height, WidthofyourContents)];`

Comment: check the frames of your button than.. also check if you are adding it to the right view and thats view in front or not..

Answer (score 0):

Scroller.contentSize =CGSizeMake([imgArray count]*75, 60);
otherwise,Please try to test with rounded rect buttons,its helpful for identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add horizontal scrollview with in the each tableview cell , 
then you must add the horizontal scroll view with in the tableview cell ,that means add the the horizontal scrollview in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method.

//

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         // Configure the cell...
         if (cell == nil) 
         {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
          }

int x = 13;
int y=13;
UIScrollView *horizontalScroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
[horizontalScroll setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(790, 60))];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    UIButton *button= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(x, 0, 45, 22);
    [button setTag:i];
    [button setTitle:@"08:30" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0/255 green:234.0/255 blue:234.0/255 alpha:1]];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:13.0];
    [horizontalScroll addSubview:button];
    x +=62;

  }
  [cell addSubview:horizontalScroll];
}
```